Trying to catch exceptions while turning string array into ints
I have a text document with an list of numbers experated by "|".
Ex:
0|0|2
1|0|1
1|1|0
2|0|1
2|1|0
2|2|1
3|0|0
3|1|1
3|2|0
3|3|1

I am generating this though code and all ways have an extra line at the bottom. I know i will always have this line and have writen my code accordingly, with a -1 value when creating an int array. The problem is when i have two lines instead of one after editing the file. outside of going into the file to remove the extra line i wanted the code to be able to ignore this problem.
my current code which works with no extra line:
while(scc.hasNextLine()){  
    String[] temp = scc.nextLine().split("\\|");
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){             
        arr[points][j] = Integer.parseInt(temp[j]);
    }         
    points++;
}
scc.close();

This works and gives no exceptions while only one line is at the bottom. but when there are two I have "NumberFormatException" from having a blank line with no ints on it.
I cant share all of my code as its very large and uses multiple custom functions. thank you for any assistence you can provide.
I tried to catch the excpetion using the following:
while(scc.hasNextLine()){
    String[] temp = scc.nextLine().split("\\|");
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        try{
            arr[points][j] = Integer.parseInt(temp[j]);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ignore){}
    }
    points++;
}
scc.close();

This generated a new error of "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" when ignore both my output becomes only one line of code instead of a list of numbers.

read the line into a variable like String line = scc.nextLine();, then check line.isEmpty()or some other validation. Then split it, also make sure that the resulting array has temp.length == 3. If not, ignore that line too.

Instead of doing j < 3 (a "magic number"), you might want either j < temp.length;, or to raise an exception if a non-empty line with temp.length != 3 is found (so you can rectify that issue).

j < temp.length probabaly is not a good solution - it will eventually hide input errors -- you probably also want to check if points is not getting too large

@Rogue in this case "magic number" is best as i know the file will only generate 3 destinct values. my "arrayindexoutofboundsExceptions" was comming from  points++ location inside of the for loop. by moving the for loop inside of my try statement I no longer recieved the array error.

I'd be careful "ignoring" exceptions, they usually shouldn't be thrown if your code is executing correctly. Regarding avoiding magic numbers in this case is essentially future-proofing habits: what if you changed the number of columns to 4? Now you have to go find the number 3 in arbitrary places. Having either a constant (private static final int ROW_LEN = 3) or acting on what you really care about ("all numbers in the row" i.e. temp.length) will make your code more robust.

String.isEmpty
If you merely want to ignore blank lines, check the length of the line.
String line = scc.nextLine() ;
if ( ! line.isEmpty() ) { … } // Ignore any empty lines. 

Array.length
Check all your inputs, including the number of fields in each line of incoming text.
String line = scc.nextLine() ;
if ( ! line.isEmpty() ) // Ignore any empty lines. 
{
    String[] parts = line.split( "\\|" );
    if ( parts.length == 3 ) 
    {
        … handle valid input
    }
    else
    {
        … handle faulty input
    }
}

Code points
In real work, I would scan each line, examining all code points, to verify that all characters are either a digit or the vertical bar character used here as a delimiter.
// Every character must be either a digit or a VERTICAL BAR. 
// The code point for VERTICAL BAR (`|`) character is 124 (0x7C). 
if ( line.codePoints().filter( codePoint -> ! ( Character.isDigit( codePoint ) || codePoint == 124 ) ).count() > 0L ) { … handle unexpected characters … }

FYI, Character.isDigit checks for more digits than just ISO-LATIN-1 digits ('0' through '9'). So you may want to write more narrow test.

thank you. I imediatly tried this. and while it has fixed the issue im having the same issue of ignoring both exceptions. probably hard to help without all the code. but thank you i genuinly would have not though of that solution.

@GeorgeVolz Glad you solved your problem! Instead of adding "Solved" to the end of your title, please accept this answer using the checkmark button to show your gratitude and signal that the question's been answered.

@GeorgeVolz Glad to help. The concept to remember is never trust input. Verify your assumptions about incoming data before any processing.
